# ImageGrab is not accessed by pylance

Tags: python, pylance

Looking to use PILLOW (`PIL`) to do an `imagegrab`.  The purpose of the `imagegrab` is to view a box on the screen to see incoming things in a flash game.  I did `pip install pillow` in my terminal.  I want to put `from PIL import imagegrab`  When I put that text into where I write my script it says:

> "ImageGrab isn't accessed by pylance".

I'm not sure what the issue is with the library for PILLOW or what I should do to fix this.  FYI I'm very new to coding, this is week 1 for me.

Error Code in Visual Studio Code:
[image: 1]

Comment: @Mario, this wasn't an error per se, the OP is just not very familiar with the tooling they are using. So there isn't a trace to show for it. It is literally a GUI tooltip

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning from the static code analyzer PyLance saying you are not using `ImageGrab` in your code yet (it's an idle import, basically). It shouldn't affect the execution of the code.